# MATLAB - why does this index exceed the matrix dimensions?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multidimensional-array, matrix

Hi  I have this code which keeps giving me a "index exceeds matrix dimensions" error. I am trying to start the loop for h=1, d= 1 for 24 "h" and 3 "d" with a value for the "battery_capacity" matrix =2, but this seems to contradict in terms of the matrix sizing.
Any help is appreciated! Could the "h-1" be causing the problem. The error is on the second time the "battery_capacity" is written
My code is
     for idx_number_panels = 1:length(number_panels) % range of PV panel units examined

```
for number_turbines = 0:2 % range of wind turbine units examined
  for number_batteries = 1:50 % range of battery units examined
    for h=2:25 %# hours
      for d = 1:number_of_days %# which day
        battery_capacity(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1, ...
                         number_batteries, 1, 1) =  2*number_batteries;
        %% Charging
        battery_charging(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1, ...
                         number_batteries, h, d) ...
          = hourly_surplus(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1, ...
                          number_batteries, h, d) ...
            + battery_capacity(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1, ...
                               number_batteries, h-1,d);
    end
  end
end
```

DEBUGGER

```
error line 134 

battery_charging(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h,d) =        hourly_surplus(idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h,d)...
    K>> sz = size(battery_charging)

sz =

 1     1     1     2

K>> index = [idx_number_panels, number_turbines+1 ,number_batteries, h-1,d]

index =

 1     1     1     1     2

K>> ndims(battery_charging)

ans =

  4
```

Running "battery_charging" in the command line

```
>> battery_charging

battery_charging(:,:,1,1) =

 0


battery_charging(:,:,1,2) =

  0
```

> > 

Answer (score 2):

Easier than trying to figure out what the problem is from the code is to debug as follows. First, set the debugger to break on error:

```
>> dbstop if error
```

Now, run your code again. When you get to the error, you should be met with the debug prompt:

```
K>>
```

You can now inspect the values of the different indexes and the shape of your matrices at the time of your error, and figure out where the problem is coming from.

Comment: thanks Isaac. I have done your suggestion and copied what I see in the command prompt in the original post above. I don't really understand how to interpret this as "battery_charging" seems to have 4 dimensions and "battery_capacity 5 dimensions. Does the below mean that the problem is on the "h" dimension??

Comment: You are clearly missing a dimension, yes. Do you not initialize this matrix yourself?

Comment: I believe I do using the for loops at the beginning. however, I am trying to use the "battery_capacity" value that from the previous "h" as shown in the "h-1" format in the code above. could this have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: I have also added what I get when I run "battery_charging" in the command line. it seems to run from d = 1 to 2 and then crash

Comment: Try initializing your variables to the size you want them to be. (i.e. with `battery_charging = zeros(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5);`)

Comment: ok I think the problem is the "battery_capacity" matrix. Do you know how to set the very first value of the first dimension as I have tried to do above for h=1 and d=1 and then reference that value for h=2 d=1 and then the new value for h=3 and d=1 etc etc for the whole equation?

Comment: I can run the code with setting a "battery_capacity" equal to a number but it is the same number over all dimensions wheras I am trying to calculate from the equations in my code